# Issue in converting an SVG vector tile map to use Canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas, vector-tiles

I'm working on visualizing a map of polling divisions of the Canadian election. I managed to get a working SVG version [here.](https://github.com/ktrieu/electoral-codex-web/blob/master/static/js/map_viz.js)

However, the performance was poor, so I figured I would move to drawing on Canvas instead. I put together what I assumed would be a direct conversion:

```
class VectorMap {

constructor(map_file, element_id) {
    this.map_file = map_file;
    this.root = $(`#${element_id}`)[0];
    this.init_map();
}

init_map() {
    var root_rect = this.root.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.width = root_rect.width;
    this.height = 720; 

    this.zoom = d3.zoom()
        .on('zoom', _ => this.onZoom(d3.event.transform));

    var canvas = d3.select(this.root).append('canvas')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height)
        .call(this.zoom);
    this.context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');

    this.projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(1 / 2 / Math.PI)
        .translate([0, 0]);

    this.path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(this.projection)
        .context(this.context);

    this.onZoom(d3.zoomIdentity);
}

onZoom(transform) {       
    var tiler = d3.tile()
        .size([this.width, this.height])
        .scale(transform.k)
        .translate([transform.x, transform.y])

    //init drawing parameters
    this.context.save();
    this.context.fillStyle = 'gray';
    this.context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    //this.context.lineWidth = 1 / transform.k;
    this.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.context.scale(transform.k, transform.k);
    this.context.translate(transform.x, transform.y);

    var tiles = tiler();
    tiles.forEach(tile => {
        console.log(tile);
        var zoom = tile[2];
        var x = tile[0];
        var y = tile[1];
        if (zoom > 10) {
            // since these are vector tiles we can just overzoom the z10 ones
            x = Math.floor(x / Math.pow(2, zoom - 10));
            y = Math.floor(y / Math.pow(2, zoom - 10));
            zoom = 10;
        }
        d3.json(`/maps/${zoom}/${x}/${y}/`)
            .then(function(json) {
                json.features.forEach(feature => {
                    this.context.beginPath();
                    path(feature);
                    this.context.closePath();
                    this.context.stroke();
                    this.context.fill();
                });
            });
    });
    this.context.restore();
}
```

but it draws nothing. Obviously something has changed between SVG and Canvas, but I'm not sure what. Just drawing rectangles seems to work, so I'm assuming it's an issue with the canvas path generator.

Comment: "Performance is poor" when you're using SVG is generally a sign that whatever you're doing, you're doing really inefficiently, so: there is nothing inherently poor about SVG performance, you can make lightning fast full-Canada maps using HTML5, SVG, and some JS, so it's probably worth figuring out _why_ your SVG solution is performing poorly, rather than trying to do lossy, expensive bitmap conversions.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you, but this is a big file. By polling divisions, I mean every individual, in a high school gym, polling station. There are around 50,000 such features in the file I'm using, and if I do nothing to the GeoJSON file, it's about half a gigabyte in size. I've sliced it up into vector tiles, but even limiting each tile at around 4000 features gets unacceptably slow.

Comment: Yeah but you're not _showing_ all polling stations at a time, a human can only see so much before pixels are pixels. A map of all the ridings in Burnaby with all polling stations marked, say, will have zero performance issues, so the trick is to _not render_ what you don't need to render. For managing that kind of SVG, something like React is actually super useful, because it lets you "turn off" large parts of your data so they don't bog down the browser. Using the canvas is not going to speed things up if you're not also going to do "data-weeding" based on the view (bbox, zoom, etc)

Comment: I've already done that with the vector tiles, but at current levels of simplification, it's still slow and and the utility tells me I am only displaying ten percent of the features at the worst case zoom levels. That being said, I don't really notice a difference in visual quality. My main concern is that I will be dropping features even at the highest zoom level, and increasing the max zoom makes the tile database take exponentially longer to prepare.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I guess I have to eat my words because upping the zoom level to 12 and limiting to 1000 features per tile seems to have finally gotten performance under control. I'll leave the question open because it is still a problem, but for now I can move on.